# What is the solution for opacity inconsistency in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opacity

I am having a simple problem w.r.t. the alpha opacity for background color only in IE9.

I am copying the code used,

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown custom-select-lang">
    <select name="one" class="languageDrop dropdown-select">
        <option value="1">ENGLISH</option>
        <option value="2">Option #1</option>
        <option value="3">Option #2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown { display: inline-block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 38px; width: 110px; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}

.dropdown:after { content: ''; position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 9px; right: 10px; width: 0; height: 0; border: 4px dashed; border-color: #888888 transparent; pointer-events: none;}

.dropdown:after { margin-top: 8px; border-top-style: solid; border-bottom: none;}

.dropdown-select { position: relative; width: 130%; margin: 0; padding: 6px; height: 38px;  font-size: 12px; color: #62717a; border: 0; border-radius: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; float: left;}
```

I am also using the following hack meant for only IE9:

```
/* IE9 only */
:root .currChangeDrop.dropdown-select{ width: 150%; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are adding the background to the wrong div.
Add the background to your .dropdown-select class

so your class would now look like the following:

```
.dropdown-select {background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); position: relative; width: 130%; margin: 0; padding: 6px; height: 38px;  font-size: 12px; color: #62717a; border: 0; border-radius: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; float: left;}
```

Do not need a css hack for IE9 only for IE8

Let me know if this works

...

Comment: I have the background-color for the class dropdown-select. But still it is not working.

Comment: Why not just make a 1px x 1px transparent png background image and add it to your css that always works? That way you won't need any hack or have to worry about cross broser compatibility....@PratikBasak

Comment: thanks for the solution. I was trying to avoid using image of any sort so it skipped my mind..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, choose the on you prefer.

Either add a class `.transparent` on your markup and add this code below in your stylesheet :

```
.transparent {
    zoom: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Or simply add this to your css declaration.

```
.you-selector {
   /*some stuff here*/
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

The first solution is advised by [css-tricks]http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/